# Is there a way to make sure that explorer stays in RAM and does not get off-loaded to the harddrive when it hasn't been used for a while?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

XP.

Related to this question, but I cannot find an answer. This is another way of trying to do the same thing.

[Is there a way to change the layout of Windows Start window?](https://superuser.com/questions/177095/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-layout-of-windows-start-window)

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have been able to find out, the answer to my question is "No".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's how explorer works. Explorer is the shell (operating environment), including the desktop and start menu. While I've never looked at it at a deep level, I have serious doubts that explorer gets paged out to the hard drive.

Comment: Yes, Explorer is the shell, including the start menu and the taskbar (I believe the desktop is handled elsewhere). Still, the Explorer is a regular Windows process (explorer.exe), so I see no reason why it wouldn't be paged out. As a matter of fact, I have seen Explorer hang (all open Explorer windows become white rectangles) when the system was overloaded; it recoverd when things settled down after a few seconds.

Comment: Is there a way to stop it from paging out?Thanks.

Comment: No there is no way to prevent it. Windows is not designed that way. If a program is not in use and something else needs the physical RAM, it will be paged out. In point of fact, SQL Server used to allow you to lock tables in memory, but they took this out in later versions because the automatic memory management in Windows is better than you.

Comment: What I'm implying in my answer is that certain processes are never paged out, such as the kernel and device drivers and my assumption is that because explorer is the actual operating environment that it too is never paged out. I'm going to do some testing to try and confirm or debunk that assumption.